# Fluent InverseProperty Problems since EF6 upgrade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

We are expriencing a problem since upgrading to EF6 from EF5. We used to have the model like this:

```
[Table("tblOrganisations")]
public class Organisation
{
```

...

```
    [InverseProperty("OrganisationId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
```

...
    }

```
[Table("tblClients")]
public class Client : IBelongTo, IHaveADescription, IEntity<int>, IAuditable
{
    [Column("OrgID")]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Fluent Syntax manages the connections:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
                    .HasOptional(x => x.Client);
```

Which was working fine until EF5. When we upgraded to EF6 however it seems like we are no longer able to use base types for navigational properties (i.e. OrganisationId but we can only use objects such as Organisation).

```
    [InverseProperty("Organisation")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

This is fine except it creates SQL like this which is invalid as we want to match OrgID against orgID instead of clientId against orgId.: 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblOrganisations] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ClientID] = [Extent2].[OrgID]

Can anyone give us any insight as to why this is happening and how we can resolve it?